# How to generate/create service endpoint from WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I want to learn JAX-WS. I have the wsdl document with me, I'm using eclipse web-service plug-in and I have generated java beans skeleton. Now, I want to create the service endpoint using the wsdl document. I checked over the net but nothing of any use. Kindly suggest me how to generate the endpoint from wsdl document.

Answer (score -2):

For example, i am using a WSDL link

http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

go to command Prompt and create a folder :

D:> mkdir SourceGen

D:> cd SourceGen

D:/SourceGen> mkdir Src

D:/SourceGen>wsimport -keep -s Src http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

NOTE : Here some important term are need to describe

```
  -keep : it preserve all the generated .java files
  -s    : store the file as given location at Src
```

> Generated Source

go to D:/SourceGen/Src location where you will get all the required .java files and their .class files

Now, copy all the java files and drag all .java files into the WebContent -> lib folder of client consumer

Now, your client will use these files as Service Endpoint interface.